# What happens if I send a null pointer to fclose()?

Tags: c

For example:

```
FILE* file_name;
file_name = fopen("some.txt", "r");  // some.txt isn't exist
if (file_name !=NULL)
  printf("nice");
fclose(file_name);
```

What happens in `fclose`?

Comment: What happens if you compile and run that code?

Comment: The documentation is fairly clear on this. Is there anything in particular that makes you doubt?

Comment: This is a good question. The [documentation](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fclose.3.html) doesn't mention null pointers, but also doesn't mention any null pointer checks. Compiling and running the code to find out won't help in the long run if the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @alter_igel [Yes it does](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4p1):  "Each of the following statements applies unless explicitly stated otherwise in the detailed descriptions that follow: **If an argument to a function has an invalid value** (such as a value outside the domain of the function, or a pointer outside the address space of the program, or a null pointer, or a pointer to non-modifiable storage when the corresponding parameter is not const-qualified) or a type (after promotion) not expected by a function with variable number of arguments, **the behavior is undefined.**"

Comment: @alter_igel and MS VC does too: [fclose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fclose-fcloseall?view=msvc-170). The C standard states "The `fclose` function returns zero if the stream was successfully closed, or `EOF` if any errors were detected." What else do you think would be the result of passing a `NULL` pointer?

Comment: @WeatherVane passing NULL is different, it produces UB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Passing a `NULL` pointer to `fclose` triggers undefined behavior.

The `fclose` function is documented as a library function in section 7.21.5.1 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), and section 7.1.4p1 states the following regarding library functions:

> Each of the following statements applies unless explicitly stated
> otherwise in the detailed descriptions that follow: **If an argument to
> a function has an invalid value** (such as a value outside the domain of
> the function, or a pointer outside the address space of the program,
> **or a null pointer**, or a pointer to non-modifiable storage when the
> corresponding parameter is not const-qualified) or a type (after
> promotion) not expected by a function with variable number of
> arguments, **the behavior is undefined**.

Section 7.21.5.1 makes no explicit mention of a `NULL` pointer being passed to `fclose`, so the above statement applies.

Answer (score 4):

The C standard does not define the behavior.<sup>1</sup>  Some implementations may test the passed pointer and disregard a null pointer and may return success or may return failure. Other implementations may crash. You should not do this without a special purpose such as aiding diagnosis of a bug or investigating how it affects program vulnerabilities.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> The behavior is undefined becaue the specification for `fclose` in C 2018 7.21.5.1 specifies what `fclose` does when passed a pointer to a stream and does not specify what it does when passed a null pointer, and 7.1.4 1 says “… If an argument to a [standard library] function has an invalid value (such as… a null pointer…)…, the behavior is undefined.”